# What permissions are needed to view cross-project work items in "Pull Request Work Items - List"?

Tags: azure-devops, permissions, azure-pipelines

I have a step in an Azure Pipeline that needs to look up information about work items related to a pull request.

A minimal version of the pipeline is:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  displayName: 'Look up related work items'
- script: |
    pr_url="$SYSTEM_COLLECTIONURI$SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/git/repositories/$BUILD_REPOSITORY_ID/pullrequests/$SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTID?api-version=6.0"
    pr_data=$(curl --no-progress-meter --location "$pr_url" \
      --header "Authorization: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" | jq)
    pr_workitem_url=$(echo "$pr_data" | jq -r '._links.workItems.href')
    pr_workitem_data=$(curl --no-progress-meter --location "$pr_workitem_url" \
      --header "Authorization: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" | jq)
    if [ "$(echo "$pr_workitem_data" | jq -r '.count')" != "1" ]; then
      echo "Can't find related work item";
      exit 1;
    fi
```

This is the PR pipeline for ProjA. If I create a pull request with a work item that's owned by ProjB (another project in the same organization), then this step fails -- `pr_workitem_data` contains `{"count":0, "value":[]}`. I want to know what permisisons I have to give "ProjA Build Service (orgname)" to have the work item data populated (with `{"count":1, "value":[...]}`). [The API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-work-items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) doesn't say what's included when, but I know there is *some* set of permisisons that works.

If I do any of the following, the API call returns the work item, but I want to find the *minimal* permissions needed.

- Turning off "Limit Job Authorization Scope" in the pipeline settings.
- Putting the "ProjA Build Service (orgname)" user in ProjB's "Project Administrators" group.

  - Attempting to mimic the administrator permissions (both in "Project Settings -> General -> Permissions" and "Project Settings -> Repositories -> Permissions") directly on the build service user, however, doesn't seem to work. If this did work, I could narrow down the permissions on my own. Is there another set of permissions I'm not looking at?

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed another set of permissions. You need to grant the build service the "View work items in this node" permission for an area containing the work item.

You can do this by going to "Project Settings -> Boards -> Project Configuration -> Areas", clicking the ellipsis next to the area, then clicking "Security".

[image: the settings page]